# Async ArrayFormula still freezes Excel

Tags: asynchronous, excel-dna

I am running an ArrayFormula asynchronously using ExcelAsyncUtil.Run. This formula has around 20 columns and 1000-5000 rows.

It still freezes my excel, and I think it is when ExcelDNA converts/renders my "wait message". How can I refactor this to work better?

Here is some sample code.

```
    [ExcelFunction(
      Name = "MySlowFunction",
      Description = "...",
      IsHidden = false)]
    public static object MySlowFunction(DateTime reportDate, object[,] filters)
    {
        var result = ExcelAsyncUtil.Run("MySlowFunction",
            new object[] { reportDate, filters },
            () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    return // Run slow query to server here....
                }
                catch (Exception asyncError)
                {
                    return new object[,] { { asyncError.Message } };
                }
            });

        return ParseResult(result);
    }


    public static object ParseResult(object result)
    {
        if (result.Equals(ExcelError.ExcelErrorNA))
        {
            return "Wait...";
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Excel-DNA async implementation is based on Excel's RTD feature. RTD does not work well when called from an array formula.

I suggest you split your function into an async function that returns a single 'handle' (while internally storing the data in a dictionary or something) and a second (non-async) function that unpacks that data, taking the handle as input and returning the array from the internal store.

It's a bit more inconvenient to use, as you need an extra cell to hold the handle, but will be much more reliable.

Comment: Thank you Govert. This is how I used to implement this. I am a bit worried about memory leaks. Do you know of a simple way to clear the dictionary if the cell that calls the async function gets changed?

Comment: Instead of using ExcelAsyncUtil.Run, use ExcelAsyncUtil.Observe with an IObservable, then the Dispose will reliable allow you to clean up. See this add-in as an example: https://github.com/ratesquant/ACQ/tree/master/ACQ.Excel/Handles